# ui-router sref to grandchild with parameter in child

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

How can I create a sref that will take me to a grandchild state, when I have a parameter in the URL for the child state?

Here's some pseudocode:

```
.state( 'foo', {url:'/', template:'<div ui-view></div><a ui-sref="foo.bar.baz(bar: 'bing')">Bing Baz</a>'})
.state( 'foo.bar', {url:':bar',abstract: true, templateURL:'bar.tpl.html'})
.state( 'foo.bar.baz', {url:'/baz', template:'I am a baz, and if you clicked from the foo state, I should be a Bing Baz!'});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is [an example](http://plnkr.co/edit/BB1BPDbeoIYUkjaHHpmv?p=preview). We can call it like this *(I've removed the abstract to show more variants, but the middle state could be abstract! just not directly accessible via url)*:

```
<a ui-sref="foo">foo</a>
<a ui-sref="foo.bar({bar:'bing'})">foo.bar({bar:'bing'})</a>
<a ui-sref="foo.bar.baz({bar:'bing'})">foo.bar.baz({bar:'bing'})</a>
```

And there are redefined states, which are providing calls to children state with a relative stat syntax:

```
  $stateProvider
    .state('foo', {
      url: '/',
      template: '<div><h3>I. The foo state</h3>' + 
      'Child : <a ui-sref=".bar({bar: \'bing\'})">.bar.baz({bar: \'bing\'})</a>' +
      '<div ui-view></div>' +
      ' </div>', 
    })
    .state('foo.bar', {
      url: ':bar',
      //abstract: true,
      template: '<div><h4>II. The foo.bar state</h4>' + 
      'Child : <a ui-sref=".baz({bar: \'bing\'})">.baz({bar: \'bing\'})</a>' +
      '<div ui-view></div>' +
      ' </div>',
    })
    .state('foo.bar.baz', {
      url: '/baz',
      template: '<div><h5>III. The foo.bar.baz state</h5>' + 
      '<div ui-view></div>' +
      ' </div>',
    });
```

See more in the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BB1BPDbeoIYUkjaHHpmv?p=preview)

Comment: In my non-pseudocode, I wasn't properly escaping the variable that I was representing as bar:'bing'. Looking at your code, it's largely the same as my pseudocode, but I realized my error.