# Ui-Router Deep Nested States with Parents

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

I have been searching around, and have found nothing that works as I need yet, or anything that works in general.

I have states for an application I am building, as follows:

`app` - Main Parent State

`facebook` - Parent state of all routes for Facebook

`adwords` - Parent state of all routes for Adwords

`bing` - Parent state of all routes for Bing

`...` - There are a lot more... A lot...

So, for instance, if I wanted a Facebook overview, it would be `app.facebook.overview`. However, it hasn't worked in any ways I have tried (`dot` annotation, `parent` in the declaration, etc.)

```
$stateProvider
    .state('app', {
        url: '',
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'assets/views/default.html'
    })
    .state('app.facebook', {
        url: '/facebook',
        abstract: true
    })
    .state('app.facebook.overview', {
        url: '/overview',
        templateUrl: '/assets/views/facebook/overview/overview.html',
        controller: 'FacebookOverviewCtrl'
    });
```

I have tried every combination of `abstract` and `parent`, along with the `dot` annotation. I haven't been able to get it to work. It fails giving me the following error:

```
Could not resolve 'app.facebook.overview' from state 'app'
```

What am I doing wrong here? I don't understand, I have followed documentation for it, along with looked at numerous questions here, on Stackoverflow. Any ideas?

EDIT:

I have figured out the problem. Elementary mistake. I didn't include the module in the main `angular.module` declaration. Well... 4 am coding for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm basing my answer on this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24338598/3323569)
Basically, you just need to set the url of `/facebook` to `url: ':facebook'` and that should do the trick.
http://plnkr.co/edit/LQLYTu0YHlvTdB26vQcP

Answer (score 0):

I would like to state, for the fact, that I am stupid.

Here is a plunk with it working:
https://plnkr.co/edit/aAeoucDidw3NX7QJqise?p=preview

It would have helped in my code if I included the module.

```
var App = angular.module('app', [
    '... other modules ...',
    'ui.router',
    '... other modules ...',
]);
```

Fix:

```
var App = angular.module('app', [
    '... other modules ...',
    'ui.router',
    'app.facebook',
    '... other modules ...',
]);
```

Elementary mistake, but worth keeping it here since it took me quite a while to figure out how to do deep nested states with `ui-router`. Some things I learned:

- You do NOT need to have a URL on abstract states, but if you do, it prepends down

  - For instance: `app` has no url, `app.facebook` has a url of `'/facebook'`, and `app.facebook.overview` has a url of `'/overview'`. Meaning the url that will be used will end up being `/facebook/overview`
- You can have states nested as deep as you want.
- If you go further down, you need to include `template: '<ui-view></ui-view>'` on your state declaration, so it will continue to input the next state as needed.

  - For instance: `app` has a template page, that has `<ui-view></ui-view>` in it, but `app.facebook` must also have `template: '<ui-view></ui-view>'` declared so it will insert the page you want below it (`app.facebook.overview`).

I hope this helps more people than just me. It took a while to figure it out, but the plunk has the code working in it. Now, that's dealt with. I feel like I can finally move on...